# Mapping Histograms on the image

Tags: computer-vision, histogram, feature-extraction

Features extracted using the HoG method is a single vector. Is there any way to map these histograms on the image and use the mapped image for the further processing to extract the features.

```
img = imread('cameraman.tif');
[featureVector,hogVisualization] = extractHOGFeatures(img);
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "map these histograms on the image"?

Comment: I mean how we can use histogram image for further processing